# "CORS Error" but Chrome sent the request anyway

Tags: chrome, cors

I have created a page to attack a CSRF unprotected endpoint.
This endpoint accepts only JSON as payload, so I have used fetch with `credentials: "include"` properties. The page run locally using file:// protocol.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      fetch(vulnerableEndpoint, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify(myPayload),
        redirect: "follow",
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CORS policies should prevent the browser calling another domain with credentials.
However using Chrome :

- In network tab :

| Name | Status | Type | Initiator | Size | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| endpoint | CORS error | fetch | xxxxx | 0 B | 235 ms |

- When I click to see item details

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Request URL | vulnerable-website/endpoint |
| Request Method | POST |
| Status Code | 200 |
| Referrer Policy | strict-origin-when-cross-origin |

And actually my request is sent and the remote server handle it as a legit request.
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not set in response header so I guess it use default value.

**I know CORS is not a defense again CSRF.**

I have read OWASP guidelines : https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

**However why my request is sent by Chrome ?** It seems to be a security issue.

I have done the same with Firefox and firefox block the request and the response is flagged as a 403 one.

I use Chrome v114.0.5735.134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fetch specication permits “simple requests” that are equivalent to form submissions. This is the case here: Your POST request does exactly the same as a form with `method="post"` and `action="vulnerable-website/endpoint"`, so it wouldn't make sense to block it while allowing the same request to be made with a form submission.

[Only specific requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#examples_of_access_control_scenarios) trigger a CORS preflight and will be blocked if the server doesn't provide the right `Access-Control` headers.

Comment: Okay, that's why using custom header could mitigate CSRF , on endpoint which expects to be called through XHR only, without having to generate and check a token validity as OWASP mentionned. It makes senses now

Comment: Concise and accurate answer; upvoted. One nit-pick: the Fetch API actually introduced ways to send simple requests that are not possible via a form submission; for instance, a `HEAD` request.